# Parcel + Pug - Multiple pages causes build to break

Tags: pug, parceljs

I am using parcel + pug for a project and everything was working great until I tried to add another page. It seems like it causes the bundler to fail.

`Cannot find module '../node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/builtins/css-loader.js'`

If I remove the reference to the styles or scripts it will work - however of course I need those.

**App Structure**

```
-- Root
 -- html
  -- index.pug
  -- about.pug
 -- styles
  -- style.scss
 -- scripts
  -- index.js
```

The markup in the pages is pretty simple

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= ""
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.scss")
  body
    main
      div.container
    script(type="module", src="../scripts/index.js")
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel html/*",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "browserslist": [
    "last 3 and_chr versions",
    "last 3 chrome versions",
    "last 3 opera versions",
    "last 3 ios_saf versions",
    "last 3 safari versions"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/css": "1.8.2",
    "@parcel/transformer-css": "2.5.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-pug": "2.5.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "2.5.0",
    "cssnano": "5.1.8",
    "parcel": "2.5.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "1.3.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.14",
    "pug": "3.0.2",
    "sass": "1.51.0"
  }
}
```

**Update**
This seems to happen when I link to any of the sub pages
`a(href="/about.pug") About`

Comment: You should remove `parcel-bundler` from your `package.json` and re-run `npm`/`yarn`. `parcel-bundler` is the old, unmaintained version 1 of parcel, and when it is installed side-by-side with `parcel` (the re-written version 2), it will stomp on your `parcel` command (e.g. your `"parcel html/*"` is actually running v1, not v2). You can also tell this because the error message refers to `../node_modules/parcel-bundler/`, which is v1.